# Do activities in the Data Flow count towards the Pipeline Activity limit of 40?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I essentially want two sinks for 1 output. It's seeming like I'll have to duplicate my Pipeline and change the sink to the other Sink location.

I'd like to avoid that as much as possible.

So, I have a pipeline with 30 Copy Activities. Plain and simple, source to sink.

If I changed those into Data flows which split the Sink between two different sources (using the new Branch feature), would that increase the count of activities or do Data flows count as 1 activity?

Comment: 1 Data Flow run should equal 1 activity.

Comment: @BriaNikole try to make pipeline generic. If the activities are common then you can pass the values via the parameter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Flow is one active. But in Data Flow active, we can create more flows to copy data or do data conversion from source and sink.

We can create more sources to one sink,  but one sink for one output, just for now there we can't achieve two sinks for one output.

**The max number of 40 activities allowed per pipeline.**  Data Flow doesn't have the source and sink limits. I just tested and we can create more than 40 flows. That mean that  we can create 40 data flows in one pipeline, and each data flow can contains more than 40 flows(source to sink).

Like you said, you have a pipeline with 30 Copy Activities, you have two ways to build the pipeline:

1. **30 actives:** copy active 1 + copy active 2 + copy active 3 + ... + copy active 30.
2. **1 active Data Flow:** source1-->sink 1, source2-->sink2, ... ,source30-->sink30.

Data Factory doesn't charge for the actives number, only charge the for the amount of the amount of data transferring and how many resource you used in Data Factory.